# Determining the "quality" of a video in Python

Tags: python, video

I am trying to compute a rough "quality" metric for a video, which takes the following into consideration:

- "Smoothness" of video; i.e., the opposite of how "choppy" it is
- Image quality; i.e. if there are a lot of compression artifacts, the quality should decrease in size

I came across https://github.com/aizvorski/scikit-video, but the code seems to be littered with `FIXME`s and `TODO`s, and on top of that there's barely any comments or documentation.

Is there a Python library, or even a program with a CLI, for computing video quality, or perhaps a set of libraries that will help me compute the above two metrics separately?

Answer (score 0):

#### Image Quality

I would think that "Image Quality" is largely a function of bit-depth (or effective bit-depth) and bit-rate.

You can parse [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) output to get this information.  PIL or PyQt/PySide can also do this.

#### Smoothness

For smoothness, you may need to use some type of optical flow algorithm and get deltas from frame to frame.

[OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html) looks like a project that does many of these things.